# Integrate search bar (like in product controller for packs) in custom module controller

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm facing an issue when I'm try to integrate the same search bar as the one in product controller for product packs.

[image]
(this one)

I've been scrolling through the whole product controller but didn't find where the search bar is rendered.

I found few parts nearly related of the input in product.js, but nothing really interesting.

What I'm trying to do is implement the same search bar with product suggestions, I will find out later how to "save" it like in product controller when you create a pack.

Answer (score 0):

Backoffice product page had been migrated in Symfony, form is built in a twig template inside:

```
 src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/ProductPage/Panels/essentials.html.twig
 src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Product/form.html.twig
```

While JS handler is here :

```
admin/themes/new-theme/js/product-page/product-search-autocomplete.js
```

Comment: Thank you really much, I'll try to find ou how to use twig tpl in smarty tpl, thanks for your help.